# React Router render vs component giving me error

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom

I am trying to use react router auth redirects as it shows here (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow). I am currently receiving the error cannot receive property 'state' of undefined.

The error appears in my login component which is currently called in React Router through `Route path="/login" render={() => Login } exact`. But when I change it to `Route path="/login" component={Login} exact` it renders and does not give me the error. I do need to use the render function because I need it for a callback. Any Ideas on why it is acting this way.

```
function Protected() {
  return <h3>Protected</h3>;
}
function AuthExample() {
  return (
<React.Fragment>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
      <PrivateRoute path="/" render={() => <Protected />} exact />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</React.Fragment>
  );
}

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  redirectToReferrer: false,
};
}

handleSubmit(event) {
fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
  this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
});
}

render() {
const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;
if (redirectToReferrer === true) {
  this.props.history.push(from.pathname);
}
return (
  <button
    type="submit"
    onClick={this.handleSubmit}
    className="btn btn-primary"
  >
    Login
  </button>
);
}
}
```

I have also taken fakeAuth and PrivateRoute directly from the Link I provided above. Here is a link to the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-cherry-3yv8e?fontsize=14.
Also as a kind of side task when I click login it does not redirect me to the protected page. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to wrap your component using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter)

```
export default withRouter(Login);
```

**Note:**
In your post you write this

```
Route path="/login" render={() => Login } exact
```

which is wrong (unless it is a typo), it should be,

```
<Route path="/login" render={() => <Login /> } exact />
```

Comment: Yea sorry for some reason if used '>' in the text everything within it would just not appear in the writeup so I decided to get rid of it. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: You should notice `render={() => Login }` from your post and `render={() => <Login /> }` from my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help ive gotten myself into other errors but I made it over the first hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that's undefined is most likely "this.props.location". Did you remember to wrap the component in "withRouter"? If not, you won't have access to it.